# Duplicate symbols, GTMOAuth2 and Facebook SDK for IOS both using SBJSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, duplicate-symbol, sbjson

I have an app in which I have implemented facebook login. I copied the sources from the facebook sdk directly into my project. Now I need to add google login. This time I have added GTMOAuth2 as a static library. (I also have the source for this too but I added as a static library for no specific reason). The problem is they are both using SBJson and I get duplicate symbols. It appears that the SBJson in the facebook sdk is newer than the one in the GTMOAuth2 library. I'm a noob I never had duplicate symbols before, what should I do? Are there solutions to this specific problem or to resolving duplicate symbols in general? Do I just delete stuff that appears twice until it works, are there some linker settings? Thanks.

**Update - What I tried:**

Added both projects as a static library.

- I tried deleting the SBJSON.h/m files from GTMOAuth2, result: json parse error after google login:
- I tried deleting the SBJSON.h/m files from the Facebook iOS SDK; result: json parse error after facebook login.

Can I make these two versions of SBJSON magically coexist in my app without duplicate symbols? Do I have to modify one library to work with the ONE SBJSON I decite to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using SBJSON from the facebook sdk. I just removed SBJSON from the GTMOAuth2 library to avoid duplicate symbol as suggested by `Ishu`. 
The next problem is that GTMOAuth2 tries to use SBJSONParser first and that class doesn't have objectWithString:error: method, only SBJSON has the method. I modified the code to use SBJSON class, and don't even try to use SBJSONParser because it doesn't work. In the original version `SBJsonParser` was checked first and then SBJSON.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithJSONData:(NSData *)data {
    ...
    // try SBJsonParser or SBJSON
    Class jsonParseClass = NSClassFromString(@"SBJSON");
    /*
    if (!jsonParseClass) {
      jsonParseClass = NSClassFromString(@"SBJsonParser");
    }
    */
    if (jsonParseClass) {
      GTMOAuth2ParserClass *parser = [[[jsonParseClass alloc] init] autorelease];
      NSString *jsonStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
      if (jsonStr) {
        obj = [parser objectWithString:jsonStr error:&error];
#if DEBUG
        if (error) {
          NSLog(@"%@ error %@ parsing %@", NSStringFromClass(jsonParseClass),
                error, jsonStr);
        }
#endif
        return obj;
      }
    }
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
[Here](http://groups.google.com/group/gtm-oauth2/browse_thread/thread/e6a1d70d1efa37a) I asked the same question in the GTM-OAuth2 discussion group. This happened after I answered the question, but I forgot to update my answer here. In summary this is what I did:

- Use both Facebook SDK and GTMOAuth2 as static libraries (probably this is not necessary)
- Get latest version of SBJSON from [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://github.com/stig/json-framework/blob/master/Classes/SBJsonParser.h&usg=AFQjCNGrChvVD-IPhb9jpP7-TDlQBx4fXQ)
- Replace the SBJSON in Facebook SDK with this one
- Delete the SBJSON sources from GTM-OAuth2 (or remove them from the build phase)

This leaves you with the most up to date SBJSON library included in the Facebook SDK. Both Facebook SDK and GTM-OAuth2 will use that one. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

yes delete the SBJSON of GTMOAuth2 library (since it is older version).

Comment: Well ok, but I'm not entirely sure which one is the newest.

Comment: Ok not a problem delete any one you want. your work also can be done with old one.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. It gives me an exception `NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: -[SBJsonParser objectWithString:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x45bb1c0` I have no idea what exactly is wrong but it is something related to the json parser, if nothing else works I may modify the oauth library to make it work with the json parser from the facebook sdk

Comment: @gyozokudor I believe it might be because the SBJsonParser doesn't have the objectWithString method. Ensure that you're building the correct source file that contains this method. I recall not being able to see that method when I looked at the facebook SBJson...